# Tensorflow: partially decode binary data

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering if there is a native tensorflow function that allows to decode a binary file (for example a tfrecord) starting from a given byte (offset) and reading the following N bytes, without decoding the entire file.

This has been implemented for jpeg images: [tf.image.decode_and_crop_jpeg](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_and_crop_jpeg)
but I cannot find a way to do the same thing with any binary file.
This would be very useful when the cropping window is much smaller than the whole data.

Currently, I am using a custom tf.py_func as mapping function of a Dataset object. It works, but with all the limitation of a custom py_func.
Is there a native tensorflow way to do the same thing?